# How to get Multiple inputs with single variable?

Tags: bash

I was writing a Multiboot script, but stucked in a little mess, I wrote a function like this,

> read -p "Drag & drop the iso's on Terminal : " isofile1

Now I applied condition that when just Enter pressed, like '' is passed, it move to next section, but I wanna store all iso files from $isofile to different incremental variables, I would like to get multi variables with single variable, any way to achieve it ??

I tried

```
$isofile1==$(isofile1+1) and different ways but no luck...
```

I want like isofile1=first input, isofile2=2nd input, and so on until no input provided...

EDIT: I used another method now, i just echo all inputs to tempfile, now i just want to get each line from that file using head -n 1, and put it in file location where rsync will perform copy of iso file in usb, any clue in getting all lines one by one into a variable which is copying files 
??

Comment: You *don't* want to store multiple values in a single variable, unless you are *positive* that none of the values can contain whitespace or characters like `*` or `?`. Given that the input values appear to be arbitrary file paths, that's not a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
read -p "Drag & drop the iso's on Terminal : " isofiles
> iso1 iso2 iso3 ...
for iso in $isofiles; do
    echo "$iso"
done
```

Comment: this needs 3 inputs but i wanna give it variable inputs everytime, i tried another way which was to separate 1,2,3... with variable num, then i did $isofile$num and make num=$((num+1)) so it gets updated in each loop, the issue came when i try to give values of isofile$num=$isofile this just says file or directory not exists, i just wanna give isofile$num the value of $isofile,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get "multi variables with single variable" is to use an array.  If I understand it correctly, you are trying to read a list of file paths on a single line of input and put each of them into a different variable.  A better approach may be to make each file path a separate element in an array.  The `read` command can do that with the `-a` option.  This code

```
read -r -p "Drag & drop the iso's on Terminal : " -a isofiles
```

will read a line containing several file paths and put the first in `${isofiles[0]}`, the second in `${isofiles[1]}`, and so on.

If the list of files is created by dropping files on a terminal window then you may have a problem.  When I tested this on a Linux system I found that the file paths were quoted in the terminal window.  The code above will keep quote characters when it sets up the array elements.  It will also get incorrect paths if any of the paths contain whitespace characters.  More elaborate code is required if you need to deal correctly with quoted file paths in the input.

In response to the EDIT in the question, example Bash code to read a list of files line-by-line from a file called 'tempfile' and copy them to a directory called 'destdir' is:

```
while IFS= read -r file || [[ -n $file ]] ; do
    cp -- "$file" destdir
done <tempfile
```

Using `IFS=` means that file paths can have whitespace characters in them.  Using `-r` with `read` avoids problems with backslash characters in file paths.  The `[[ -n $file ]]` test means that the code will work even if the last file in the input file (`tempfile`) is not terminated.

See [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?") for more information about reading input line-by-line in Bash.

Comment: i tried both solution, but its just keep getting inputs, where is condition for move ahead ??

Comment: I think I mis-read the question.  I've re-written the answer to reflect my current understanding of the question.

Comment: you mean it will read just 1 line with all paths ?? to be more accurate, i have applied empty input condition like when empty input is given, it will skip all and move to next section while preserving inputs, but issue is am not able to pass value of one variable to other one with increment loop, even arrays will work but iw ant one input each time,

Comment: also, i have applied another condition to remove first and last quote of input, so i will have file start with /media/ or /home/ and ends with .iso